# A computational criterion of irreducibility in $\mathbb Z[X]$?

Tags: polynomials, prime-numbers, irreducible-polynomials, computational-mathematics, polynomial-rings

If $f\in\mathbb Z[X]$ and there are $x_1,\dots, x_n\in\mathbb Z_+$, where $n>\deg f$, such that $f(x_i)\in\mathbb P$, $i=1,\dots n$, then $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Z$. Because, if $\,f=g\cdot h$ then either $g(x_i)=1$ or $h(x_i)=1$ which can't happen 
$n>\deg g+\deg h$ times.

> But what about the opposite? Are there non constant, irreducible polynomials
>   $p\in\mathbb Z[X]$ such that
>
> $x_1,\dots, x_n\in\mathbb Z_+$ and  $p(x_i)\in\mathbb P$ for all
>   $i=1,\dots,n$ $\:\implies\:$  $n\leq \deg p$?

Comment: I think this question is pleny interesting even without the $n \leq \deg p$ limitation. Just that there are only finitely many inputs that yield primes.

Comment: @Arthur: the limitation would be nice for an eventual computational test method. Else I agree.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2942032/589.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your claim seems to be negative.

For example, if we take $f(x)=x^3-x+3$. It is an irreducible polynomial of degree $3$, and for each positive integer $n$, $f(n)$ is divided by $3$ ( By Fermat's little theorem). Since $f(n)>3$ when $n>2$, the only $n$ such that $f(n)\in \mathbb{P}$ is just $1$.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems that the irreducibility of $f$ can be deduced from the method in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_polynomial#Over_the_integers as $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Z_2$. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I know how to proceed from your example.